# Line of matrix not affected by function

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, row

So I have a module to input a matrix that will return a regular matrix,for example:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[]
```

I made a module to manage a specific row(list) of this matrix:

```
def line_manage(matrix):
          theline = int(input('wich row'))
 thelist = [matrix[theline-1]]
```

And if I try to do this after

```
print(max(thelist))
```

I doesnt work,it just print the selected row and doesnt print the max of it.Actually,any operation i try to do to the row dont affect it at all,it just print back the row.And I dont get it.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please review your code and indentation, and give a full example of code (including inputs) we can actually run to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in:

```
thelist = [matrix[theline-1]]
```

Change it to:

```
thelist = matrix[theline-1]
```

Without this change variable `thelist` holds the list with one element and this element is the row you want to retrieve.

```
max([[1, 2, 3]])
```

returns `[1, 2, 3]`
but

```
max([1, 2, 3])
```

returns `3`.